# Factors affecting storage field key generation in ink!

Tags: ink, smart-contract, upgradable-contract

I've got a couple of questions regarding the storage fields' key generation using `AutoKey` in the context of upgradable contracts and partial `ManualKey` usage.

1. Does the use of `ManualKey` in some storage fields impact the keys generated by `AutoKey` for the rest of the fields?
2. Can the change in the ordering of the fields which uses `ManualKey` impact the fields (keys) generated by `AutoKey`?
3. Should we use `ManualKey` for every storage field in the case of upgradable contracts?

   3.a. If so does that imply that each field will be loaded lazily? and does this result in higher read/write overhead?
4. Can the use of sequentially numbered ManualKeys cause collisions?
5. What other things to keep in mind while using `ManualKey` for upgradable contracts?

A sample storage struct for reference:

```rust
#[ink(storage)]
pub struct SampleStruct {
    A: AccountId,
    B: Mapping<AccountId, Balance, ManualKey<100>>,
    C: String, 
    D: Lazy<Vec<AccountId>, ManualKey<101>>,
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. In your example - not. Each field has a unique auto-storage key based on the field's name.

   In more complex cases like the one below, the `ManualKey` of the `Parent` may affect the storage keys of the `Child` type:

   ```rust
   #[ink::storage_item]
   pub Parent {
       child_1: Child,
       child_2: Child<ManualKey<123>>,
   }

   #[ink::storage_item]
   pub struct Child<ParentKey: StorageKey = AutoKey> {
       A: AccountId,
       B: Mapping<AccountId, Balance, ManualKey<100, ParentKey>>,
       C: String, 
       D: Lazy<Vec<AccountId>, ManualKey<101, ParentKey>>,
   }
   ```
2. No. The field ordering works regardless of `AutoKey` or `ManualKey`. Because the auto storage key is generated based on the field's name, not on the position like in Solidity, so you can treat `ManualKey` in the same way as `AutoKey`, but instead of the name, you use a pre-defined number.

   The ordering matters for the layout of your structure. You can change the order of layoutless fields without any problem. You can put them in any order or place, shuffle as you wish. You can't change the order of layoutful fields or remove them.

   The field is layoutless if its type is `Lazy`, `Mapping`, or layoutless type. The type is layoutless if all its fields are layoutless.
   The field is layoutful if it is not layoutless=)

   Consequently, all [packed](https://use.ink/datastructures/storage-layout/#packed-vs-non-packed-layout) are layoutful by default, but not each non-packed type is layoutless.
3. You can use `ManualKey` if you plan to change the field's name in the future, or if you are afraid that ink! will change the storage key calculation strategy; otherwise, `AutoKey` should be enough for you.

   Regarding upgradability: It depends on your use case. Making each field layoutless allows you to add/remove/shuffle them as you wish. It decreases the chance of corrupting the storage layout. However, doing that for every storage field may not always be necessary or efficient.

   a. Yes, it adds more overhead, but also may be useful in case of heavy fields that you don't use too much(so it's okay to load them lazily not too often). More about that you can read [here](https://use.ink/datastructures/storage-layout/#eager-loading-vs-lazy-loading).
4. In your example  - no, if each key is unique within one struct. In the complex example from my answer to question `1`: the usage of the `ManualKey` when you want to use the same type several times causes problems if you don't specify `<ParentKey: StorageKey = AutoKey>` during the declaration of the `Child` type and don't pass the `ParentKey` into `ManualKey<101, ParentKey>`.
5. I will put notes regarding upgradable contracts overall:

   1. The Usage of the `ManualKey` or `AutoKey` for packed types is useless.
   2. Use `ManualKey` if you plan to change the name of the field or are afraid that ink! can change the algorithm of the storage key calculation. Otherwise, `AutoKey` should be enough.
   3. Each non-packed type should specify `<ParentKey: StorageKey>` generic during declaration to avoid a potential collision with other types. It guarantees that if types have the same field's names the auto storage key will be unique.
   4. If you want to use `ManualKey` for your fields, then you need to propagate the parent storage key to each of your no-packed fields with `ManualKey` like `ManualKey<123, ParentKey>`.
   5. The fields that can be updated in the future should be layoutless. The fields that will remain during the full lifecycle of the contract or can be dropped/ignored later can be layoutful.
      5a. To be able to drop the field, you can put it into `Option`. And if you don't need the field anymore, you can always set it to `None`.

   You can read the suggestions from the [OpenBrush](https://learn.brushfam.io/docs/OpenBrush/smart-contracts/upgradeable) on how to write upgradable contracts.

Answers on  the follow-up question:

> If the ManualKey assigned to each field is unique, Can they still overlap with each other?

Storage keys can overlap in the complex struct case if you didn't propagate the parent storage key.

> Is it possible that a given field (maybe some complex struct?) occupies more than one storage key?

Technically the field occupies either zero or one storage slot. But the type itself may have many fields that occupy many storage slots. For example, the `Mapping` itself doesn't occupy any storage slot, but each element occupies its own single storage.

Comment: Thanks! I now feel more aware of how the data is mapped under the hood. I wasn't aware that key generation is based on field name rather than positioning. I think it's worthwhile to mention it somewhere in the ink docs!

Comment: The following texts seem conflicting with each other? `1. Auto storage key is generated based on the field's name, not on the position` and `2. The ordering matters for the layout of your structure.`

Comment: The storage key values(like `100` and `101`) don't depend on the ordering. But the data layout depends on it(actual bytes that we serialize into the storage) for layoutful types.

Answer (score 2):

answer for your questions about storage field key generation using AutoKey and ManualKey in the context of upgradable contracts.

1 - Does the use of ManualKey in some storage fields impact the keys generated by AutoKey for the rest of the fields?

No, using ManualKey in some storage fields does not impact the keys generated by AutoKey for the rest of the fields. AutoKey generates sequential integer keys starting from 0, regardless of whether some fields use ManualKey or not. So, you can use ManualKey for some fields and AutoKey for others without any issues.

2 - Can the change in the ordering of the fields which uses ManualKey impact the fields (keys) generated by AutoKey?

No, the ordering of the fields that use ManualKey does not impact the keys generated by AutoKey. AutoKey generates keys sequentially based on the number of storage fields, regardless of their order or the use of ManualKey.

3 - Should we use ManualKey for every storage field in the case of upgradable contracts?

It depends on your use case. ManualKey can be useful for controlling the storage key of a specific field, which can be important for upgradable contracts. However, using ManualKey for every storage field may not always be necessary or efficient.

3a -  If so does that imply that each field will be loaded lazily? and does this result in higher read/write overhead?

Yes, if you use Lazy storage for fields that use ManualKey, it implies that those fields will be loaded lazily, which can result in higher read/write overhead. However, if you don't use Lazy storage, the field will be eagerly loaded.

4 - Can the use of sequentially numbered ManualKeys cause collisions?

Yes, if you use sequentially numbered ManualKeys for multiple fields, it can cause collisions. It's important to ensure that each ManualKey value is unique within the storage struct.

Here are some things to keep in mind while using ManualKey for upgradable contracts:

Make sure to choose unique values for each ManualKey to avoid collisions.
Using Lazy storage for fields that use ManualKey can result in higher read/write overhead.
Be mindful of the storage size and cost when choosing ManualKey values.
If you plan on upgrading the contract, be sure to consider the impact on storage layout and key generation when making changes to the storage struct.

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed answer! Could you please elaborate more on this.  
`> 4 - Can the use of sequentially numbered ManualKeys cause collisions?
Yes, if you use sequentially numbered ManualKeys for multiple fields, it can cause collisions. It's important to ensure that each ManualKey value is unique within the storage struct.`

If the ManualKey assigned to each field is unique, Can they still overlap with each other? Is it possible that a given field (maybe some complex struct?) occupies more than one storage key? Wouldn't it through error like exceeded buffer capacity in such case?